# UIpickerview containing 2 component, second should cotain 1component minus selected row ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uipicker

pickerview containing 2 component both having same data when I select first component then the selected component should not appear in second component

Comment: Please put a little more effort into your post, as it stands right now I have no idea what is wrong with your code and no idea how to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us answer your question, please add some code showing us what you've tried already. This will help you get succinct, quick and relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

After you make a selection in the first component, remove the item from the datasource for the second component & reload the picker components. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but on the basic of what i understood:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 string = [fistPickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
//do what ever logic you want 
   for(NSString str in secondArray)
   {
    if([string isEqualToString:str])
    {
      [secondPickerArray removeObject:str],
    }
  }
   [picker reloadAllComponent];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

write below code in didSelectRow method

```
if(component == 0) {

string = [yourarray objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

then in titleForRow method,

```
    if(component == 1) { if([string isEqualToString:[yourarray objectAtIndex:row]]) { break; return nil; else{ return string; }

    }

}
```

Comment: There are a couple of errors here. If you break up the second snippet on to separate lines with a more legible indentation, I think the issues will be self evident.